# C# Defining List type once before multiple use

Tags: c#, list, types

I have searched thoroughly as best as i could for an answer to this question. I might not be formulating it correctly due to the lack of my experience with C#, but here goes.

Say i have a list type

```
List<List<int>> teams;
```

And wish to use this type in multiple classes, with different fieldnames, without defining its type over and over again. Something like this:

```
List<TeamType> teams;
List<TeamType> winningTeams;
List<TeamType> losingTeams;
```

How would i accomplish this?

I have been looking into interfaces, but im not sure if/how they can help tackle this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each line of code you've posted is syntactically correct and defines a `List<T>` variable.  It's not clear to me what the problem is.

Comment: Why don't you define `Team` or `TeamType` as a class and define different properties etc about the team?

Comment: `public class TeamType : List<int> {}`. Pointless but that's how you'd do it.

Comment: possibly use var instead of List<TeamType>  for example var teams = ......

Comment: Do you mean you want one `List<List<TeamType>>` to replace you're 3 `List<TeamType>` variables?

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around how a `List<List<int>>` represents a list of teams. Jersey numbers? Team member IDs?

Comment: I have a strong feeling that you're asking the wrong question altogether. You should take a step back and describe at a higher level what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Like @Rufus said, the approach feels weird. I feel like a `class Team { public List<int> Members { get; } = new List<int>(); }` is more natural. Then you can have a `List<Team> teams` object. You can add more properties to the `Team` class (Name? Coach?) as appropriate. That's what I'd expect to see anyway.

Comment: You appear to be asking how to use `TeamType` as an alias for `List<int>`. See marked duplicate for that answer. If that's not what you're asking, then your question is really unclear. You need to edit it so that it includes a good [mcve] showing exactly what you've got now, and a detailed explanation of what that code does, and what you want instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what it is you mean, you keep having to define

```
List<List<int>> variable
```

and want to define a `List<int>` as a type in order to avoid typing that declaration over and over again.

I would personally suggest creating a class called Team that has a `List<int>` attribute, then instead of typing `List<List<int>>` every time to define a *set of teams* you can just type `List<Team>` instead. This makes more sense.

Although, I don't understand how a `List<int>` would represent a team, but as long as it makes sense within the context of your code, this will work fine.

It also will allow you to expand the functionality of your class the further you go in development. You could include attributes in your class definition to represent win-loss numbers, people involved with the team (coaches/managers/owners), etc.

Answer (score 0):

From an object oriented design perspective, `winningTeams` and `losingTeams` are aggregates over data rather than the data itself.

To find this information there needs to be a data structure to represent a team and its metrics.

```
public class Team
{
    public int TeamNumber { get; set; }
    public int Wins { get; set; }
    public int Losses { get; set; }
}
```

Then ask questions about the data to create statistics:

```
var teams = new List<Team>
{
    new Team { TeamNumber = 1, Wins = 5, Losses = 3 },
    new Team { TeamNumber = 2, Wins = 1, Losses = 5 },
    new Team { TeamNumber = 3, Wins = 1, Losses = 1 }
};
```

Who are the winning teams? Where Wins > Loses

```
var winningTeams = teams.Where(team => team.Wins > team.Loses).ToList();
// TeamNumber = 1
```

Who are the losing teams? Where Loses >= Wins

```
var losingTeams = teams.Where(team => team.Loses >= Wins).ToList();
// TeamNumber = 2, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want something that acts like a typedef for some generic `List<T>`, you can create a simple derived class like so:

```
public class TeamType : List<int> { }
```

and then use it anywhere you would have used the generic type:

```
List<TeamType> teams;
List<TeamType> winningTeams;
List<TeamType> losingTeams;
```